# How to handle sporadic component unmount error with ReactJS/Preact?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I'm building a ReactJS SPA with Preact for learning purposes. Every once in a while, a component from a library I use ([`react-frame-component`](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component)) will throw an exception when being unmounted, which breaks other parts of the application. This is a fairly sporadic error, and as such I've not been able to create a test-case that reproduces it.

I do know about [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), and did try wrapping the problematic `<Frame>` component in one, but it hasn't made a difference. Specifically, the error message I get is

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
    at Frame.getMountTarget (Frame.js:112)
    at Frame.componentWillUnmount (Frame.js:95)
    at unmountComponent (preact.js:355)
    at unmountComponent (preact.js:358)
    at recollectNodeTree (preact.js:198)
    at removeChildren (preact.js:208)
    at recollectNodeTree (preact.js:201)
    at removeChildren (preact.js:208)
    at recollectNodeTree (preact.js:201)
    at removeChildren (preact.js:208)
```

I'm unsure how to go about capturing this error myself, or even just debugging it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: provide code examples with all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was resolved by just making a "custom" iframe:

```
let src = 'iframe src here';

<iframe id="my-awesome-frame"
        srcdoc={src} sandbox="allow-same-origin">
</iframe>
```